# Show $\deg P=1$(Complex) where $P(z)$ polynomial satisfying $z\in \Bbb{R}\iff P(z)\in \Bbb{R}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show $\deg P=1$ where $P(z)$ polynomial satisfying $z\in \Bbb{R}\iff P(z)\in \Bbb{R}$. I was firstly advised to show the following: 
Denote: $P(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$,
1. Show $v_y\ge 0$ or $v_y\le0$ on the real axis. 
2. Conclude that $u$ is monotone on the real axis.

I know this question is a duplicate but I found other answers a bit complex, which also did not use the hints, which I still don't understand how to prove. I could really use any hint or reference.